# Limit of power series

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Exercise 3.4.22 Let $f_n(x) = x^n$ for n ∈ N.
Show that the sequence $(f_n)_(n∈N)$ converges pointwise to the function f(x) = 0 on the interval (−1, 1)

The definition of pointwise convergence: We say that a function f : X → F is the pointwise limit
of the sequence $(f_n
)
_(n∈N)$
if, for every x ∈ X, lim
n→∞ $f_n(x)$ = f (x)

What I want:

for all ε>0, for all x∈(-1,1), there exists an N s.t. if n>N, then $|x^n-0|=|x^n|<ε$

if x = 0, clearly $x^n$ = 0. if x∈(0,1), or if x∈(-1,0), I'm unsure of what to do. Can I use the ratio test on $\sum x^n$? Since $|x^(n+1)/x^n|=|x|<1, then \sum x^n$ converges absolutely. Thus (I'm not sure where I can find a proof/theorem for this but it seems very obvious to me),  $\lim_{x\to \infty \!\,} x^n = 0$

What I don't get is why this would prove that $x^n$ is, in particular, pointwise convergent.

Comment: Where is the power series?

Comment: Oh thanks I think you helped me realize my mistake. By the ratio test, the sum of x^n converges absolutely, so x^n converges to 0. There is a theorem or a result that states this right? I can't find it anywhere but I'm really bad at looking up math-related queries.

Comment: You are talking about the series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k$?

Comment: There is no series, where is the series? Or do you mean sequence.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll edit the post to include the entire question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ratio test gives that for all $x\in (-1,1)$ you have $f_n(x) = x^n\to 0$. Hence the sequence $f_n$ converges pointwise by definition.